The component does not render when set the manualPersist to true
From the redux-persist v6.0.0 doc: persistStore(store, [config, callback])

If you want to avoid that the persistence starts immediately after calling persistStore, set the option manualPersist. Example: { manualPersist: true } Persistence can then be started at any point with peristor.persist(). You usually want to do this if your storage is not ready when the persistStore call is made.

Try to use manualPersist config:
store.ts:
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { PersistorOptions, persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { testSlice } from './testSlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  test: testSlice.reducer,
});

const presistedReducer = persistReducer(
  {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
  },
  rootReducer
);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: presistedReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store, {
  manualPersist: true,
} as PersistorOptions);

main.tsx:
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistor, store } from './store';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

App.tsx:
import { persistor } from './store';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          persistor.persist();
        }}
      >
        persist
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

The <App/> component does not render when set manualPersist: true. There is no error log in the browser console. What happens? My understanding is that this configuration is for manually persisting state. So I want to persist the state when clicking a button.
stackblitz

When the manualPersist option is not used and the app starts you can see the persist/PERSIST and persist/REHYDRATE actions dispatched to the store when the app mounts.

But when you specify this option they are not.

It seems the PersistGate doesn't render the app UI until the store has been updated.
See PersistGate README:

PersistGate delays the rendering of your app's UI until your
persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux.

As a test you could render the button element outside the PersistGate to see that the button renders but the app UI does not until you click the button and persist and hydrate the store.
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        persistor.persist();
      }}
    >
      persist
    </button>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

When the button is clicked you'll see the localStorage update with the store value, the persistor is bootstrapped, the store is updated, and the app UI is then rendered.
The PersistGate subscribes to the persistor and waits for it to be bootstrapped before it renders the app UI.
Source code
componentDidMount() {
  this._unsubscribe = this.props.persistor.subscribe(
    this.handlePersistorState
  )
  this.handlePersistorState()
}

handlePersistorState = () => {
  const { persistor } = this.props
  let { bootstrapped } = persistor.getState()
  if (bootstrapped) {
    if (this.props.onBeforeLift) {
      Promise.resolve(this.props.onBeforeLift())
        .finally(() => this.setState({ bootstrapped: true }))
    } else {
      this.setState({ bootstrapped: true })
    }
    this._unsubscribe && this._unsubscribe()
  }
}

...
render() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    if (typeof this.props.children === 'function' && this.props.loading)
      console.error(
        'redux-persist: PersistGate expects either a function child or loading prop, but not both. The loading prop will be ignored.'
      )
  }
  if (typeof this.props.children === 'function') {
    return this.props.children(this.state.bootstrapped)
  }

  return this.state.bootstrapped ? this.props.children : this.props.loading
}

If the goal is to simply delay rendering the UI until the storage/etc is ready then it appears the intent is for persistor.persist() to be called programmatically as part of the app mounting/bootstrapping flow instead of as some manual asynchronous UI event, e.g. like a user clicking a button.
Once persistor.persist() is called it looks like normal "auto-magical" state persistence occurs.
If the goal is to only persist manually then it would appear that your code would need to call persistor.persist() to persist and hydrate the store, then immediately call persistor.pause() to pause automatically persisting state updates so the UI could call persistor.flush to manually flush states out to localStorage.
